# Redirecting specific IPs to another page

Tags: apache, redirect, httpserver

I'm trying to redirect specific IPs to another page but with the code I have below it's redirecting every visitor.  this is what I have:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On

 Rewrite Cond %{(}REMOTE_ADDR} ^103\.11\.52\.115 [OR]
 Rewrite Cond %{(}REMOTE_ADDR} ^103\.11\.52\.116 [OR]
 Rewrite Cond %{(}REMOTE_ADDR} ^103\.11\.52\.118 [OR]
 Rewrite Cond %{(}REMOTE_ADDR} ^176\.67\.84\.253 [OR]
 Rewrite Cond %{(}REMOTE_ADDR} ^176\.67\.81\.161
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.anotherpageonsitehere.com/page/04/index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

how do I only redirect the IPs I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Syntax error I'd say... Try this instead:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On

 RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^103\.11\.52\.115 [OR]
 RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^103\.11\.52\.116 [OR]
 RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^103\.11\.52\.118 [OR]
 RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^176\.67\.84\.253 [OR]
 RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^176\.67\.81\.161
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.anotherpageonsitehere.com/page/04/index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: this isnt working either.. all traffic gets redirected

Comment: Apologies - there was an extra syntax error. You have `Rewrite Cond`, it should be `RewriteCond`. Have updated the answer.